# Why can't I run imported projects on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When opening Android Studio, I clicked "Imported Project (Eclipse, ADT, Gradle, etc.)" Then, I chose "Create project from existing sources". It imported all the java and xml files but the "Run" button isn't even active. Please refer to screenshots below.

[image: Run button isn't active and "Design" doesn't show any of the layouts]

Comment: check the gradle config of the project and yours

Comment: Do check your gradle for incorrect dependencies or `buildToolsVersion` or `compileSdkVersion` etc... It'd be better if you post your build.gradle(module file) and also errors from the console.

Comment: add build.gradle files